# Why are subqueries slower?

Tags: sql

Why do correlated sub-queries run slower?

Comment: Why should they be the same? You changed the logic. You were filtering based on country-average, and now you're filtering on global-average.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the first round of calculation", or "the loop continues". SQL is a declarative language, you tell it what results you want, you don't talk about loops or rounds, generally. Your first query translates to "give me all games where the number of goals is more than 3 times the average for the game-country", and the second is ""give me all games where the number of goals is more than 3 times the global average".

Comment: What do you mean by "global"? It doesn't matter that the two aliases point to the same table. Pretend they're actually two different tables that happen to have the same data in them.

Answer (score 1):

What don't you understand?

The overall average -- times 3 -- filters out fewer rows than the average by country.

As an example, the global average version is going to filter out some entire countries (low higher ones).  But the country-by-country version might be included.

Comment: @ChengYunQi . . . It is exactly the same idea, because it depends on the data.  The result is not surprising.